# Manga with a guy who relives the past lives of other people to improve them as his job

Tags: story-identification, manga

I read this manga but I forgot the name of it and haven't read it in a while, but it goes something like this.

The MC is a male who struggles with his family due to money problems. He has a sister, mom, and dad, but the mom is bedridden because she's sick. The MC gets a job where he lives in other people's lives in different time periods and tries to change the outcome to be better than what the original person did and he also gets paid for doing that.

Comment: Please visit https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question and https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question?noredirect=1&lq=1 and see if the prompts bring up more details you can [edit] in. Like, when did you first read this? Was it online? In comics? In collected volumes? Was it in English, Japanese, another language? Was it set in Japan? Were the other lives set in Japan? Were there any fantasy aspects other than the time travel?

Comment: @Venom - Welcome to the site. Was this in colour or black & white?

Comment: this could be Dimensional Mercernary? He lives in other people live help his family

Answer (score 2):

The manga's name is *[Other World Warrior](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/dimensional-mercenary)*, otherwise known as *Dimensional Mercenary*

> Would you like to find a job? Even at the cost of your soul? If so,
> then you’ve found the right place. Our job hunting advice website,
> Soul Sellers, is a site geared towards those willing to even sell
> their souls for employment; that’s right, people like you. Are you
> dealing with angels or demons? 30-year old freeloader Chul Ho Kang
> made a deal through this shady site, even selling his soul for the
> chance at what else? Money! An invitation to the other world for the
> weak and downtrodden of society for a chance to change their lot in
> life! That is the mission given to Chul Ho Kang!
>
> [image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If you get the chance, please [edit] this answer to explain why you think this is the correct manga, i.e. the ways in which it matches the one described in the question.